# How to get a certain code for an equation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm a beginner working on my first application using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2019.

I want to calculate this:

[image]

I have all W<sub>i</sub> in (list view) and also (text box).
I have all H<sub>i</sub> in (list view).

My problem is how could I multiply w<sub>i</sub> list view (or W<sub>i</sub> text box) by h<sub>i</sub> list view and get this result in a third list view ?

Comment: You can get those values from the controls(listview and text box), parse their integer values, multiply them and add them to the third listview's item collection.

Comment: Do you have the values already in something other than a listview or textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that the biggest problem you have found is getting the data from the ListViews - please note that using a Control to store data is usually a bad idea.

Note that array indexes in VB.NET (and C# and many other computer languages) start at zero (i.e. they are offsets, rather than indices as used in maths).

Once you have the data in arrays, it is easy to perform the calculation. Coming up with meaningful names for the methods and variables is also a problem.

With ListViews named ListViewW, ListViewH, and ListViewF I came up with this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rand As New Random()

    Function Fvalues(Fb As Double, weights As Double(), values As Double()) As Double()
        If weights.Length <> values.Length Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Number of weights does not equal number of values.")
        End If
        'TODO: Possibly more argument checking.

        Dim total = 0.0
        For i = 0 To weights.Length - 1
            total += weights(i) * values(i)
        Next
        'TODO: Check for total = 0.

        Dim F(weights.Length - 1) As Double

        For i = 0 To weights.Length - 1
            F(i) = Fb * weights(i) * values(i) / total
        Next

        Return F

    End Function

    Function ListViewToDoubles(lv As ListView) As Double()
        Dim d As New List(Of Double)

        For i = 0 To lv.Items.Count - 1
            Dim dbl As Double
            If Double.TryParse(lv.Items(i).Text, dbl) Then
                d.Add(dbl)
            End If
        Next

        Return d.ToArray()

    End Function

    Sub CreateSampleData()
        For i = 1 To 5
            ListViewW.Items.Add(rand.NextDouble().ToString())
            ListViewH.Items.Add(rand.Next(0, 11).ToString())
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        CreateSampleData()

        Dim weights = ListViewToDoubles(ListViewW)
        Dim values = ListViewToDoubles(ListViewH)

        Dim f = Fvalues(0.5, weights, values)

        For Each x In f
            ListViewF.Items.Add(x.ToString())
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's an amazing reply and helpful tips .. you are awesome thank you.
I have just one question you said storing data in controls is a bad idea i get my data like (wi here in this example) from external text file and i don't know how many values it will be !! and the result ( Fi here in this example ) export it to external file too .. so how i could get these values in arrays

Comment: There are several types of collections in the .net framework that can store data in memory. An example is List(Of T) where T is the type. Your do not have to know how big your list is going to be to use the .Add method.